# Search array of thing and spit it out in different column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Is there a way to break math calculation in different column   str1+str2 /Str3-str4*str5-str6  into columns like str1 ,  str2   ,  str3   str4 , str5 , str6.  There is no particular order and it may occur multiple time.

Comment: Post an example of your data and expected outcome

Comment: str1+str2 /Str3-str4*str5-str6    Data

Comment: I meant some data from your spreadsheet and a manual calculation to show the outcome.

Comment: z_C1_molpct*gC1_GHV+z_C2_molpct*gC2_GHV+z_C3_molpct*gC3_GHV+z_CO2_molpct*CO2_GHV+z_iC4_molpct*iC4_GHV+z_nC4_molpct*nC4_GHV+z_iC5_molpct*iC5_GHV+z_nC5_molpct*nC5_GHV+z_C6_molpct*gC6_GHV+z_C7Plus_molpct*gC7_GHV                the outcome i want is separate each variable into different column
Column C   z_C1_molpct       Column D     z_C2_molpct        Column E     gC1_GHV         and so on until the last calculation. Hope this helps Thank You Dan appreciate it

Comment: lets say Column A has following Data  str1+str2 /Str3-str4*str5-str6  

The out come data is as follows  
Column B  str1   Column C str2   Column D str3   Column E str5   Column F Str6  and so on.
The delimiters can be mathematical sign +  -  * /

Comment: OK, I understand. Is it just the 4 signs (+-*/) or could it be scientific chars to like ^ and %?

Answer (score 2):

This may do what you need:

```
Sub SplitOnSigns()
Dim X As Long, MyString As String, MySign As Variant, MyArr As Variant
MySign = Array("+", "-", "*", "/")
MyString = ActiveCell.Text
For X = LBound(MySign) To UBound(MySign)
    MyString = Replace(MyString, MySign(X), "|")
Next
MyArr = Split(MyString, "|")
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, UBound(MyArr) + 1).Address) = MyArr
End Sub
```

You can add more entries here:

```
MySign = Array("+", "-", "*", "/")
```

If there are more signs to split on. This assumes your data doesn't have pipes in "|" We can change the split char to an unused one if needed.

It works by progressivly replacing the signs with a pipe, it then splits the string to an array using the pipe as a split, finally it posts the array to the range next to the active cell